# D3JS javascript chart is not working properly into angular ng-switch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using angulajs for a single page and i'm changing contents with ng-switch , i want to add this http://bl.ocks.org/brattonc/5e5ce9beee483220e2f6  d3js javascript chart into ng-switch but chart is not working properly into angularjs ng-switch , i declared libraries out of ng-switch(i added libraries into head tags) , this chart is working when the page's first load but when i fired ng-switch , chart is not working properly , i think , it is about page onload but i do not know ng-switch logic.Shortly, Can i use this chart into any ng-switch properly?

Comment: do you some code to share ? (controller + template)

Comment: Ok , i will add minified clear code today for understanding

Comment: Because of ng-cloak , without ng-cloak , it is working but not working with animations , you can investigate http://codepen.io/nicely/pen/PqmLeL , select home , and you can see chart without wave animation , if i work js code into windows.onload function , wave animotion working but Is it possible into ng-swtich ?